# What is the suggested way to change animations in swift?

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit

I am using swift for my scroller game, i have my hero with different animations, running , jumping sliding etc. Each animation is packed in a different .atlas folder
What is the suggested way to change animations? This is the scenario - hero is running, when user taps the hero jumps.

The way i currently implement this is by removing running action:

```
hero.removeActionForKey("RUN")
```

and adding the jumpAction (on complete i re-initialize the running action)
Is this the suggested way to do so? when i use `removeActionForKey` do completion methods get cleaned properly (no memory leaks?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to do this. I prefer this:

```
// declare a property
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKAction *animation;

// set a repeating animation
self.animation = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:PLAYER_RUN timePerFrame:0.1]];

// or set a one time animation
self.animation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:PLAYER_JUMP timePerFrame:0.1];

// start the animation
[self startAnimation];

// animation method
-(void)startAnimation {

    [self removeActionForKey:@"animation"];

    if (![self actionForKey:@"animation"]) {

        if(self.animation != nil) {
            [self runAction:self.animation withKey:@"animation"];

        } else {

            NSLog(@"Error. Animation nil");
        }
    }
}
```

The animations themselves are arrays comprised of images stored in the image assets catalog.

```
#define PLAYER_RUN @[ \
[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"PlayerRun0"], \
[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"PlayerRun1"], \
[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"PlayerRun2"], \
[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"PlayerRun3"], \
[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"PlayerRun4"]  \
]
```